# In what instances can the word 'war' on its own i.e. without numerals and/or names/titles be used without any article?

Tags: articles

> Negotiations broke down and **war** was declared.

> **War** broke out between the two countries.

Comment: Pretty much any noun, including “war”, can take a zero article when used in an abstract sense.

Answer (score 2):

"War" has several noun definitions, including:

- a conflict
- a *state* of conflict.

Both your examples refer to declarations of war which are a *state* or *situation*, which is why they do not require an article.

Consider as an example:

- Swimming takes place at the pool.

"Swimming" is here used as a noun for the *act* of swimming. There is no need for an article.

- You can have a swim at the pool.

"Swim" is also a noun here, but because it refers to a *specific* swim, an article is used.

Likewise:

- There is war in the middle east (refers to a current state)
- There is a war in the middle east (refers to a specific conflict).

Comment: isn't swimming a gerund?

Comment: @Yukatan Not in my example, but it can be.